# SonarLint vs code error of skipping files

Tags: visual-studio-code, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint, sonarqube5.1

Skipping text document analysis because workspace folder is not synchronized yet "file:///home/htdocs/vme-laravel-api/app/Repositories/Admin/UserRepository.php"
getting this error of skipping text on soanr int in vs code

try : Skipping text document analysis because workspace folder is not synchronized yet "file:///home/htdocs/vme-laravel-api/app/Repositories/Admin/UserRepository.php"

expeccted output:
Analyzing file "file:///home/htdocs/laravel/resources/views/treatment-plan/general-adaptive/general-adaptive-info.blade.php"...
[Info  - 18:21:05.389] Found 4 issues